# Low beams do not work, high beams do

Tags: honda, headlight, crv

2007 Honda CRV, low beams do not work, but high beams do. I replaced both head lights 3 months ago due to one burning out. could it be the relay switch and how is it that I find it to change it out?

Answer (score 4):

There should be fuses for the low beams. Fuse #21 in the under dash fuse box feeds both low beams. #16 and 17 are redundant fuses for right and left. See if fuse #21 is blown, replace if needed. If 21 fuse is good then check 16 and 17. If all the fuses are good then I would suspect a bad headlamp switch or Low Bean headlamp Relay, or possibly both low beams in the headlamps are burned out.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, you are so very kind. :*)